# Forcing express server as default port AWS

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, express

I am hosting my site on an AWS ec2 instance. I want to run a Node.JS server on port 8080 (or something similar), and I want all users going to example.com, to be sent to example.com:8080. For some reason, rewriting example.com -> example.com:8080 doesn't work because AWS doesn't allow accessing example.com:someport.

How can I force all users towards example.com:8080 without using plain Redirect? (I may be completely wrong and just doing things improperly)

Comment: rewrite should work, can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Amazon does allow `example.com:8080`. You probably haven't opened port `8080` in the security group.

Comment: I just edited the security group to allow port 8080. Now my .htaccess doesn't seem to be working still. Inside it, my redirect is the following:
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} !^8080$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.example.com:8080/$1
```

Comment: For some reason, just going to https://example.com:8080, closes the connection, but http://example.com:8080 works...

Comment: The first url references https the other http. In your case you want to redirect example.com to example.com:8080. This is redirecting HTTP port 80 to HTTP port 8080. If you want to redirect https example.com you will need to redirect HTTPS port 443 to HTTP port XXX (pick another port such as 8443).

Answer (score -1):

Do you have to use raw EC2? That is probably unnecessarily low level. Can you instead use [Up](https://apex.github.io/up/) or [ElasticBeanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.html)? Either one should make this easier.

Also, why does it need to be on port 8080? My guess would be, because when you develop locally, you use that port (because one doesn't develop locally using port 80). Why not have an ENV var where you set `const port = process.env.PORT || 80`, then invoke node with `PORT=8080 node server.js` when developing locally.

Of course, node crashes. A lot. It's kind of its thing. So, you don't want to ever run the command `node filename.js` on an ec2 instance... you want to use `forever` or `pm2`. And, you really want a reverse proxy (Nginx) sending traffic to your node instance... which is why I say use Up or Beanstalk. But if you must do it yourself, [this](https://stackfame.com/deploy-nodejs-app-on-ubuntu-with-forever-and-nginx) walkthrough covers the bases.